Proof verification about relative homology groups using Poincaré duality
Let $M^m$ be a smooth connected manifold with boundary and consider its relative homology groups $H_{m-k}(M,\partial M,\mathbb{Z})$ for $k\geq1$.

Suppose now that $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a complex of dimension $k-1$. Can I can conclude that $H_{m-k}(M,\partial M)$ is trivial?

My reasoning is the following: $$H_{m-k}(M,\partial M) \simeq H^k(M) \simeq H^k(C^{k-1})\simeq \{0\},$$ where the first passage is relative Poincaré duality, and the second by homotopy equivalence.


In particular, can we always conclude that for an $m$-dimensional smooth manifold with boundary $H_{0}(M,\partial M) \simeq \{0\}$? My reasoning is analogous and I would like to know if it is correct.

$$H_{0}(M,\partial M) \simeq H^m(M) \simeq H^m(C^{m-1})\simeq \{0\},$$ by Alexander duality and since every $m$-dimensional smooth manifold with boudnary is homotopy equivalent to a $m-1$ complex.

For 1, what you wrote is correct.
For 2 it isn't: Consider $M = S^2 \sqcup D^2$. The statement is true if (and only if) $\partial M$ meets every path-component of $M$, in particular if $M$ is connected and $\partial M \neq \emptyset$, but using Poincaré-Lefshetz duality to show it is rather ridiculous: It's an elementary consequence of the definition of singular homology that $H_0(X, A) = 0$ iff the subspace $A \subseteq X$ meets every path-component of $X$ for all spaces $X$.

Thank you very much, clear! So if we instead consider $H_{m-k}(M,\partial M,\mathbb{Z})$ for $k\geq1$, with $M$ connected and with nonempty boudnary, and assume that we know by hypothesis that $M^m$ is homotopy equivalent to a $CW$-complex of dimension $m-k-2$ (assuming, that $m\geq k+2$): Is it correct that, instead, here we cannot conclude that the relative homology group $H_{m-k}(M,\partial M,\mathbb{Z})$ should be zero for "dimensional reasons" (i.e. m-k-2<m-k), since here a "free" homotopy equivalence of $M$ to the complex is not enough and we would need a relative homotopy equivalence?

You should have no trouble verifying this yourself by computing $H_*(D^n, S^{n - 1})$ and noting that $D^n \simeq *$ :)

Do you mean that even just for $k=0$, then $H_m(D^m,S^{m-1}) \simeq H_m(S^m)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, and hence even if $D^m$ is contractible (so that we have $H_m(D^m) \simeq 0$) we clearly cannot conclude that in general that $H_m(D^m,S^{m-1})$ is trivial, right?

To conclude that $H_{m-k}(A,B) \simeq H_{m-k}(C,D)$ what we would need is a relative homotopy equivalence between the pairs $(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$, that in our case would mean a relative homotopy equivalence between $(M,\partial M)$ and $(C,\emptyset)$ and not just a free homotopy between $M$ and the complex $C$. Am I correct? Thank you for your time!

That is correct, yes. But also not that you never have a homotopy equivalence $\partial M \simeq \emptyset$ unless $\partial M = \emptyset$ to begin with. ...but being homotopy equivalent to $(C, D)$ with $D$ contractible would be enough.
